# Failed to discover available identity versions

Tags: ubuntu, openstack, keystore, devstack

I am trying to deploy openstack using devstack on ubuntu 18.04 LTS.
My env is behind proxy which I have configured in both bashrc and apt.

During the deployment I am facing below error. unstack and clean is also not helping this issue.

What can I try to resolve this?

```
INFO keystone.cmd.bootstrap [None req-3b848973-f8af-48df-941a-dfee8e4d40d9 None None] Created region RegionOne
INFO keystone.cmd.bootstrap [None req-3b848973-f8af-48df-941a-dfee8e4d40d9 None None] Created admin endpoint http://10.94.60.19/identity
INFO keystone.cmd.bootstrap [None req-3b848973-f8af-48df-941a-dfee8e4d40d9 None None] Created public endpoint http://10.94.60.19/identity
+./stack.sh:main:1148                      create_keystone_accounts
+lib/keystone:create_keystone_accounts:314  local admin_project
++lib/keystone:create_keystone_accounts:315  oscwrap project show admin -f value -c id
++functions-common:oscwrap:2357             local xtrace
+++functions-common:oscwrap:2358             set +o
+++functions-common:oscwrap:2358             grep xtrace
++functions-common:oscwrap:2358             xtrace='set -o xtrace'
++functions-common:oscwrap:2359             set +o xtrace
Failed to discover available identity versions when contacting http://10.94.60.19/identity. Attempting to parse version from URL.
Could not find versioned identity endpoints when attempting to authenticate. Please check that your auth_url is correct. Forbidden (HTTP 403)
++functions-common:oscwrap:2376             return 1
+lib/keystone:create_keystone_accounts:315  admin_project=
+lib/keystone:create_keystone_accounts:1   exit_trap
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:533                  local r=1
++./stack.sh:exit_trap:534                  jobs -p
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:534                  jobs=
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:537                  [[ -n '' ]]
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:543                  '[' -f /tmp/tmp.JqPFKuVGQG ']'
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:544                  rm /tmp/tmp.JqPFKuVGQG
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:548                  kill_spinner
+./stack.sh:kill_spinner:443               '[' '!' -z '' ']'
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:550                  [[ 1 -ne 0 ]]
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:551                  echo 'Error on exit'
Error on exit
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:553                  type -p generate-subunit
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:554                  generate-subunit 1569580521 204 fail
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:556                  [[ -z /opt/stack/logs ]]
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:559                  /opt/stack/devstack/tools/worlddump.py -d /opt/stack/logs
World dumping... see /opt/stack/logs/worlddump-2019-09-27-103845.txt for details
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:568                  exit 1
stack@host-10-94-60-7:~/devstack$
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems your credentials are mismatch between services.
You are getting Forbidden (HTTP 403) which means either :

> 1. Your service credentials are incorrectly populated.
> 2. Your proxy is stopping access to http://10.94.60.19/identity. Try to set "no_proxy" environment variable for the same and check if you
>      can access it.

Comment: I'm getting the same error after run `./stack.sh`: `Failed to discover available identity versions when contacting http://192.168.131.133/identity. Attempting to parse version from URL.
Could not find versioned identity endpoints when attempting to authenticate. Please check that your auth_url is correct. Not Found (HTTP 404)`. Can you help, please?

Comment: In this case you identity service is not exposing versions on root level.